# How to read PDF file in android and how can i read the indexes in pdf file in android?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, android-package-managers, android-maven-plugin

I am going to develop an android application like foxit reader .In my application i need to find the indexes in pdf file ..please help me how can  i found the indexes in pdf file programmatic ally .....

Answer (score 0):

You can download PDFbox API to read PDF from [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html#pdfbox).